# jquery validation не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Падает скрипт на странице с ошибкой:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
```

В хеддере у меня подключены библиотеки:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Но все равно не работает. 
Есть еще одно но.. в футтере тоже подключена первая либа джиквайери 1.11.3. 
Может быть из-за этого конфликт?

Answer (score 1):

В данной ситуации возможны 2 причины:

1. На сервере отсутствует файл `jquery.validate.js`
2. Вы пытаетесь работать с плагином до его инъекции на страницу

Для проверки первого пункта попробуй загрузить через `CDN`

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
 // you validation rules
</script>
```

P.S Загружайте скрипты в подвале, не дублируйте загрузку jQuery

Comment: имеет какое-то значения порядок библиотек?

Comment: т.к у `validate` зависимость `jquery`, логично, что `jquery` необходимо загрузить раньше

Comment: проверил по двум пунктам, все подключено, скрипт все равно падает